# ClassCastException parsing Map in Scala with Jackson

Tags: scala, jackson

I'm having issues when after parsing a jsonString like this one:

```
{"AAAA": [3,4], "BBBB": [1,65]}
```

So I parse the given string as follows:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val exampleMap = parse("{\"AAAA\": [3,4], \"BBBB\": [1,65] }").values.asInstanceOf[Map[String,List[Int]]]
exampleMap: Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(AAAA -> List(3, 4), BBBB -> List(1, 65))
```

So far so good, but when I try to access a second level List or to iterate over it I have this Exception:

```
val value = exampleMap("AAAA")(0)
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.math.BigInt cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(tests.sc0.tmp:102)
at my.domain.examples.A$A164$A$A164.value$lzycompute(tests.sc0.tmp:7)
at my.domain.examples.A$A164$A$A164.value(tests.sc0.tmp:7)
at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(tests.sc0.tmp:7)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because json4s's AST structure is as follows:

```
sealed abstract class JValue
case object JNothing extends JValue // 'zero' for JValue
case object JNull extends JValue
case class JString(s: String) extends JValue
case class JDouble(num: Double) extends JValue
case class JDecimal(num: BigDecimal) extends JValue
case class JInt(num: BigInt) extends JValue
case class JBool(value: Boolean) extends JValue
case class JObject(obj: List[JField]) extends JValue
case class JArray(arr: List[JValue]) extends JValue

type JField = (String, JValue)
```

As you can see, the JInt maps to a BigInt, which is why you're getting your integers into BigInt. Then because BigInteger is not a subclass of Integer, the automated casting does not work.

Have you tried using [extractors](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extracting-values) into a Map of case classes with String and List[Int] as arguments?